# Downloading and parsing data

Tags: objective-c, json, ios

I developed this class to download a JSON from a server, parse the result and call a delegate back on the class that called it. Since I am self started I want to know if this is a good practise.

**DataController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "Movie.h"

//This class is a data controller which means that all requests on webservices should be here. We user enum to identify which request is calling this controller

typedef enum {SearchMode}RequestMode;
RequestMode currentMode;

//================

@protocol DataControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)DataControllerRequestSuccessful:(RequestMode)mode;
- (void)DataControllerRequestFailedWithReason:(NSString*)reason;

@end

//=================


@interface DataController : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>{

    NSURLConnection *conn;
    NSArray *responseArray;
    NSMutableData *responseData;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DataControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property(nonatomic,copy)NSMutableArray *movieArray;


-(id)initAndSearchForMovieWithTitle:(NSString*)title andDelegate:(id <DataControllerDelegate>)del;


@end
```

**DataController.m**

```
//We use MACRO to keep the URL. In the future when we will have more than 1 request we can change the URL for all requests from here.
#define API_URL @"http://api.nytimes.com"
//We do the same for API Key
#define API_KEY @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


#import "DataController.h"

@implementation DataController
@synthesize delegate,movieArray;

#pragma mark - Init Function
-(id)initAndSearchForMovieWithTitle:(NSString*)title andDelegate:(id<DataControllerDelegate>)del{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        currentMode=SearchMode;

        self.delegate=del;

        //Check for internet connection
        bool internet = [self internetConnectivity];

        //Sending the requests on the server
        if(internet){

            NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?query=%@&thousand-best=Y&api-key=%@&order=by-title",API_URL,title,API_KEY];
            NSLog(@"url%@",url);
            NSLog(@"url %@",url);
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

            conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            [conn start];

        }

        else
        {

            //No internet connection

            [delegate DataControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"There is no internet connection available!"];

        }




    }
    return self;

}


#pragma mark - Delegates for NSURLConnection
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
    // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
    // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
    // also serves to clear it
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared

    [responseData appendData:data];


    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //In some cases the API returns this error
    if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"Internal Server Error"]) {

        [connection cancel];

        [delegate DataControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Something went wrong. Please try again!"];


    }

}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    [connection cancel];

    //Request has finished successfuly
    [self parseJSONFor:currentMode];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [delegate DataControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Something went wrong. Please try again!"];

}

#pragma mark - Parse method
-(void)parseJSONFor:(RequestMode)mode{

    //Declaring NSError to catch any error on Serialization
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;


    //Init the dictionaries that will help us to retrieve the data from JSON
    NSDictionary *movieDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    NSDictionary *linkDataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];


    //Init the arrays that will help us to retrieve data
    responseArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    movieArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    //In this case the Switch is useless but in the future when we have more request it will help us to diferentiate the parsing for each request.
    switch (currentMode) {

        case SearchMode:{

            //Converting the JSON data to a Dictionary
            allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

            if (jsonParsingError) {

                //In case the JSON is invalid we call the failed delegate
                [delegate DataControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Something went wrong. Please try again!"];

                break;
            }      


            //Converting the "Result" object to an array so we can iterate and get all the values
            responseArray = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];


            //Looping through the array and creating the objects Movie and adding them on a new array that will hold the objects
            for(int i=0;i<responseArray.count;i++){

                Movie *mov = [[Movie alloc]init];

                movieDictionary =(NSDictionary*)[responseArray objectAtIndex:i];

                //For each string we check that there is no NSNull value because it will crash the app.

                //For the reviewer we also make sure that the first letter of its name and surname is capitalized(because sometimes the server returns all chars capital which is inconsistend-ungly
                mov.reviewer=[[self validateString:[movieDictionary objectForKey:@"byline"]] capitalizedString];
                mov.review=[self validateString:[movieDictionary objectForKey:@"capsule_review"]];
                mov.releaseDate=[self validateString:[movieDictionary objectForKey:@"dvd_release_date"]];
                mov.title=[self validateString:[movieDictionary objectForKey:@"display_title"]];
                mov.movieID=[self validateString:[movieDictionary objectForKey:@"nyt_movie_id"]];

                linkDataDictionary= (NSDictionary*)[movieDictionary objectForKey:@"link"];

                mov.reviewURL = [linkDataDictionary objectForKey:@"url"];

                [movieArray addObject:mov];

            }

            //Notyfing the ViewController that the request was successfull and the data are ready
            [delegate DataControllerRequestSuccessful:SearchMode];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}
#pragma mark - JSON Helper method
//Checks if the JSON has any NSNull values and convert to N/A string
-(NSString*)validateString:(NSString*)str{
    NSString *validatedString;

    if (str==(NSString *)[NSNull null]) {
        validatedString=@"N/A";

    }
    else{

        validatedString = str;

    }

    return validatedString;
}

#pragma mark - Internet Connectivity method
//Check the internet connectivity
-(BOOL)internetConnectivity{

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {

        return FALSE;

    }
    else
    {

        return TRUE;

    }

}
@end
```

Comment: What's the language of this code?

Comment: It's Objective-C!

Comment: I added the tag! You'll realise that the language tag is the most important in the questions :p

Comment: Yeap! I forgot about it since iOS is the most popular tag for iOS projects! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have a few comments.

- Formatting: you have a lot of extra white space. I would recommend making line breaks mean something rather than putting them automatically between almost all lines of code. This also makes the code harder to read because the outlines/structure are less obvious when there is more white space.
- Sometimes you declare a variable and use it only once. For example here (and in `(BOOL)internetConnectivity` there's the same critique):

`//Check for internet connection
        bool internet = [self internetConnectivity];`

```
    //Sending the requests on the server
    if(internet){
```

Why not condense this to:

```
    //Sending the requests on the server if there is internet
    if([self internetConnectivity]){
```

also why not make the name of this function suggestive of what it returns? For example, even better would be:

```
    //Sending the requests on the server if there is internet
    if([self hasInternetConnectivity]){
```

- Consider defining constants to hold strings with error messages. You have this message repeated a few times: `"Something went wrong. Please try again!"` In the interest of `DRY` generally and easier customization in the future, I'd recommend putting all your error messages as defined constants in a config file.
- I probably have something to learn here. Given that `delegate` is a property, why don't you refer to it as `self.delegate`? Seems good to make clear what is an instance variable vs instance property to the reader no?
- Most of your methods are quite generalizable, but then your `parseJSONFor` seems quite specific to the NYT API. Why not put all this specific stuff into its own function and not into such a generic sounding function? This might even be a function you would want to supply from the delegate (as would the url and api key ultimately).